# DEC encryption creates same results after each program start

Tags: delphi, encryption, delphi-xe2

Using DEC (Delphi Encryption Compendium Version 5.2) in Delphi XE2, I encrypt a string with the following code below.
However, AFTER EACH PROGRAM START the same sequence of encryption results are generated. I have tried to use `Randomize` in `FormCreate`, but it does not help.

```
uses
  DECUtil, DECCipher, DECHash, DECFmt;

const
  MyPW = 'MyPassword';

var
  AKDFIndex: LongWord = 1;

function MyEncryptEx(const AText: string;
                     const APassword: string;
                     ATextFormat: TDECFormatClass;
                     AHashClass: TDECHashClass;
                     ACipherMode: TCipherMode;
                     ACipherClass: TDECCipherClass): string;
var
  ASalt: Binary;
  AData: Binary;
  APass: Binary;
begin
  with ValidCipher(ACipherClass).Create, Context do
    try
      ASalt := RandomBinary(16);
      APass := ValidHash(AHashClass).KDFx(APassword[1], length(APassword) * SizeOf(APassword[1]),
               ASalt[1], length(ASalt), KeySize, TFormat_Copy, AKDFIndex);
      Mode := ACipherMode;
      Init(APass);
      SetLength(AData, length(AText) * SizeOf(AText[1]));
      Encode(AText[1], AData[1], length(AData));
      Result := ValidFormat(ATextFormat).Encode(ASalt + AData + CalcMAC);          
    finally
      Free;
      ProtectBinary(ASalt);
      ProtectBinary(AData);
      ProtectBinary(APass);
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Randomize;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnTestClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  EncrText: string;
begin
  EncrText := MyEncryptEx(edtHWID.Text, MyPW, TFormat_ESCAPE, THash_Whirlpool, cmCBCx, TCipher_Rijndael); 
end;
```

It seems that some Randomizer is not initialized after program start.
So how can I get different encryption results after each program start?

Comment: I absolutely hope for your sake that this library does not use the RTL rng!!!!!

Comment: You mean Random Number Generator? Do you know a better RNG?

Comment: It's hard to find a worse one! The rng in your library should be good. What is it?

Comment: It seems to be a "Secure protected Random Number Generator based on Yarrow". Wikipedia says Yarrow is good. Don't know what NSA says...

Comment: BTW, here is some interesting information about Yarrow and its replacement Fortuna: (https://www.schneier.com/yarrow.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [some source code](http://read.pudn.com/downloads105/doc/432325/DEC_5_1c/DEC/Part_I/DECUtil.pas__.htm). Looks like DECUtil's RandomBinary uses its own seed. You could try calling `RandomSeed(RandomSystemTime, 4)` instead of `Randomize`.

Comment: The compiler complains about `RandomSeed(RandomSystemTime, 4)`. However, just `RandomSeed;` in `FormCreate` does the trick: No more identical results after each program start. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Seeding on system time has risks. Do you know what the parameterless function call does? Do you care about security? Do you work for Adobe?

Comment: It creates a seed from Systemtime and PerformanceCounter: `CALL QueryPerformanceCounter` inside assembler code. So the PerformanceCounter should create sufficient random noise. And no, I don't work for Adobe.

Comment: BTW, the backslash character (\\) appears rather often in the encrypted result. Could that be a sign of weakness?

Comment: `QueryPerformanceCounter` is not the best idea either, it's just the system time at higher resolution.  Call [`crypt32!CryptGenRandom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379942(v=vs.85).aspx) to get encryption-grade random bytes.

Comment: BTW, what do you think about the idea to put a microphone inside the computer and use that as a source for random generation? Even when using a "silent computer", there is no natural place on earth which does not have any sound. And the statistical data derived from such a source (if computed properly) should be completely random.

Comment: And for increased security the user then could sing his own cover version of "Singing in the Rain". That should provide enough randomness:-)

Comment: I applaud you for attempting to add salt. Clearly not from the Adobe fold! ;-)

Comment: Talking about randomness clearly shows that there are no borders between programming and philosophy... :-)